# Using sudo in a Git hook to set permissions after deploy

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, git, deployment

I run a few sites on Ubuntu and I'm setting up a new deploy worflow as follows (the example uses the staging environment):

On my dev machine, I do `git push staging` which pushes to a bare repository and triggers the `post-receive` hook, which do these things:

- Checkout the project on a separate folder
- Backup the current deployed directory
- Deploy the files with rsync
- Set the appropriate permissions using a `post_deploy.sh` script

The above is working fine, except the permissions setting part.

Since I need to use `sudo` to do a `chgrp` and `chown`, I tried adding the following to `/etc/sudoers`:

`myusername ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/post_deploy.sh`

But when performing the `git push` I get this error:

`remote: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`

If I run `post_deploy.sh` directly from the deployed server I have no problems.

How can I run the `post_deploy.sh` script from the git hook? I don't mind having to type an extra password, but from what I read the askpass thing is not for the command line (am I right?).

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue with /etc/sudoers file where it has the following entry:

`Defaults    requiretty`

It is detailed in [THIS POST](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122616/why-do-i-need-a-tty-to-run-sudo-if-i-can-sudo-without-a-password)

There are two options, comment out the `Defaults requiretty` setting  from /etc/sudoers or use the pseudo-tty allocation (`-t`) argument for `ssh`.

Try the following in your post-receive script:

`ssh -t 127.0.0.1 "sudo chown user /path/to/pushfile"`

Although you will have to have `ssh` pre-shared keys configured to yourself and run it once manually to add an entry to known hosts (or find the argument to ignore this).